# Ionic not pushing to page neither rendering

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm calling this function in a provider/service to go to another page.
For example, after clicking in notification push message that I receive in app.component.ts with OneSignal or from a modal or whatever.

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {NavController} from "ionic-angular";

@Injectable()

constructor() {
}

initRootNav(rootNav: NavController) {
    console.log(rootNav);
    this.rootNav = rootNav;
}

go(page: string, params?: any) {
    this.rootNav.push(page, params)
}
```

The page does 'push' because I can see all the info in console.log but view is not rendered. Uusually works the first time and never again.

I can see all logs but I am still in page1/modal1/whatever

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad');
}

ionViewWillEnter() {
    console.log('ionViewWillEnter');
    this.getData(); / does stuff
}

ionViewDidEnter() {
    console.log('ionViewDidEnter');
}

ionViewCanEnter() {
    console.log('ionViewCanEnter');
}

ionViewWillLeave() {
    console.log('ionViewWillLeave');
}

ionViewDidLeave() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLeave');
}
```

Comment: call `initRootNav()` before you use `this.rootNav` or give us the relevant code please

Comment: I can't call initRootNav because it will make an infinite loop.
As a sidenote, it happened before too (without using navigation service) using standart this.nav.push(). The nagivation service works for all modals and pages, I guess that is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nav.setRoot() instead of nav.push()

Comment: I solved it with nav.setRoot() instead of nav.push() for this particular case where navigation isn't working, I'm not happy with this aproach but now works.

I still don't know why the navigation it's broken when doing these steps.